# I've got a bad rep

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just started the game and even though I have chosen only Paragon options, I have some renegade in my reputation. Where did this come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll keep some of your renegade rep from previous games when you import your *Mass Effect 2* save.

Comment: This is more of a comment, but I'm pretty sure my ME2 character was mixed with paragon heavy. But my ME 1 character was renegade.

Comment: some of your rep is kept when you import so that is where your renegade is from

Comment: Alright. If you edit your answer to include that I will accept. Also, do you know how it is transferred? Is it based on a threshold or is it all just percentage?

Comment: ok I did it.  i think its percent but i'm not sure